# regex lookbehind with optional word lookups

Tags: r, regex

I need to pull the names out of these strings (ex: "L. Odem" or "A. Bargani")

```
Technical foul by L. Odom
Offensive foul by A. Bargnani (drawn by D. Granger)
Flagrant foul type 1 by B. Miller (drawn by J. Smith)
Flagrant foul type 1 by A. Croshere
Flagrant foul type 2 by M. Olowokandi
Away from play foul by R. Rogers
Offensive foul by T. MacCulloch
Personal foul by D. George
```

Here's what I tried:

```
"(?<=foul by ).*"
```

This works for most but is tripped up by the flagrant fouls that have either "type 1" or "type 2" between "foul" and "by", or the strings that end with parenthetical info which always begins with "(drawn by

I feel like I'm close but could use some help to address these hurdles.

Thanks much!

Comment: Try `(?<=foul by |foul type \d by )[^()]+`. Can the numbers contain more than one digit? Are you after a `stringr` solution only, or is base R OK?

Comment: no either a 1 or 2 only after type. I'll try this out

Comment: If only `1` or `2` can be there, just `(?<=foul by |foul type [12] by )[^()]+` will do. You may trim the matches if you replace `[^()]+` with `[^()]*[^()\\s]`, see https://regex101.com/r/sqSgIT/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using str_extract but I just need to regex I think, the rest I can fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a second alternative to the lookbehind and use `[^()]+` or `[^()]*[^()\s]` to match the names up to the first `(`:

```
(?<=foul by |foul type [12] by )[^()]*[^()\s]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqSgIT/1). In R, use

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=foul by |foul type [12] by )[^()]*[^()\\s]")
```

**Regex details**

- `(?<=foul by |foul type [12] by )` - either `foul by` or `foul type 1 by` or  `foul type 2 by` must appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `[^()\s]` - a char other than whitespace, `(` and `)`.

Alternatives:

```
stringr::str_match(x, "foul(?:\\s+type\\s+\\d+)?\\s+by\\s+([^()]*[^()\\s])")[,2]
```

[This](https://regex101.com/r/sqSgIT/2) will find the names even if the whitespaces between `foul`, `type`, etc. are inconsistent, and `\d+` will match `1`, `12`, etc. (any 1+ digits)

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("foul(?:\\s+type\\s+\\d+)?\\s+by\\s+\\K[^()]*[^()\\s]", x, perl=TRUE)
```

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/sqSgIT/3) is a base R variation with a PCRE regex, it also allows inconsistent use of whitespace and any 1+ digits after `type`.

**Details**

- `foul` - a `foul` string
- `(?:\s+type\s+\d+)?` - an optional sequence

  - `\s+type\s+` - `type` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+by\s+` - `by` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `\K`- match reset operator.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are always so quick to answer my questions and in such great detail it truly is helping me get better at this.